# Possibility of running karate tests in container

Tags: docker, karate

We are trying to run karate tests from docker container and trying to have test dependencies saved locally for security reasons.

Just a couple of questions:

1. Can we have karate tests under main folder and run it as a java application?
2. If yes, then what changes are required in `build.gradle` to facilitate this?

Any further suggestions for this use case would be great for me to make progress.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this is to have Gradle installed in the Docker container, then all you need is the source code like normal.

If you really need to create a JAR, sure that is possible. As you said, move the Karate dependencies out of `test` scope and have everything under `src/main/`.

For examples of others who have done something similar[ (Maven, but you can do similar changes in Gradle), please see this thread: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/529